# What is a good way to get many inbound links to your site?

Tags: seo, backlinks

How do you get links to your site from other sites?

Comment: Belongs on webmasters. But it's argumentative, too. Best in my opinion would be to include interesting (<- subjective) content that attracts backlinks.

Comment: Naked pics everywhere.

Comment: Produce interesting content! People will like **and link** your site!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[There are lots of easy ways to find tips to help you](http://www.google.com/search?q=get%20inbound%20links). Just keep in mind that quantity of links doesn't really help you. Quality is what matters. The quicker and easier it is to get a link the less value it almost certainly has. So instead of trying to get as many links as you can, you should be focusing on getting quality links.

FYI, the best way to get quality links is to have great content on your website.

Comment: I need a +1000 button for this answer :)

Comment: yes, but like this guy, I want to know tips and tricks. my competition got 13 000 backlinks in two months. how?!

Answer (score 1):

The way to get links is create things that your audience wants. If your website is a fan site of Lady Gaga, you need to know what her fans like, dislike. What would excite them? What are they most interested in? Then build pages that reflect that. Build relationships with other similar websites and ask them to link to your content. 
http://www.ericward.com/bestpractices/

Answer (score 0):

I thing is better to exchange with a few websites with similar content with yours .